# Apache SSL Configuration and Browsers <GRIPE>

Tags: apache, browser, ssl-certificate

Of course, I should be more diligent to ensure that the server name in my Apache HTTPD.conf file match the certificate.  But the browser is clearly unhappy when the certificate doesn't match the HTTP response.

One user was alerted that "Security certificate problems may indicate an attempt to fool you or intercept any data that you send to the server."  My customer is complaining that my misconfiguration damaged her reputation, and I can see her point.

Have browser vendors concluded that if the message were less alarming and acknowledged the possibility of a misconfiguration that the floodgates of social engineering would be overwhelming?

Seems like a common mistake.  Anyone else experience similar fallout?

Comment: In my opinion the browser should just refuse to connect, period. Are you even aware of the security reasons for these checks?

Answer (score 0):

Many proxy servers operate the same way as man-in-the-middle attackers.  Lots of network security depends on these proxy servers and your proposal would make it more difficult to implement a common security practice.  Also, the check does not protect users against the obvious attack of a forged URL whose "authenticity" is validated with a matching certificate.

This design might be effective against a brute force certificate forging attack that sends millions of random forgeries.  But otherwise, it seems unlikely that the mismatch is caused by the forgery attempt of an attacker.  As far as I know, certificate forgery is practically impossible.

Comment: what? Your response seems unrelated to the original complaint. Perhaps you were responding to my comment. In any event, please read up on [man-in-the-middle attacks](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack)